# Get relative path to a folder inside OSGI Bundle

Tags: osgi, bundle, karaf

I've developed a sample OSGI bundle and deployed it into Karaf, and the bundle contains a folder on the same level as the source.

My class needs to load data from this folder, but I got an error each time:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such group file: ./data/...
```

My question is: how do I use a relative path to a folder inside an OSGI Bundle?

Comment: thanks for suchs advices ... a sample error of typing is not the end of the world ... and i m not expecting from guys like u any thinks ... just to go their way and let the other response or moderate a dummy typing mistake ,instead of writing article of 5 ligne blablablaa...

Comment: I asked you to read only once that you have written down. Not more. If you are such a big enemy of quality, I must suggest you not to try develop based on OSGi as you will never have a sense of achievement with it. Btw: This is the first time I raised my voice against the exceptionally poor quality of the question.

Comment: hhhh ok man , take it easy ,and thanks for advices ... btw , i solved the problem,...to not continue developing in OSGI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using context from bundle:

```
URL wfl = context.getBundle().getResource("data1/file.txt");
```

or

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("data1/file.txt");
            if (url != null) {          
                mFile = FileLocator.toFileURL(url).getFile();
```

Hope this help someone

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Bundle.getEntry](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getEntry(java.lang.String))? It is one the methods that can be used to access the contents of a bundle.

Comment: already try it , Bundle.getEntry Bundle.getResource, my bundle call an other one and pass to it this Path , i think the second plugin responsable of this problem.... thanks :)